# How to use jQuery in TinyMCE plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, tinymce

I created a plugin in TinyMCE 4.3.12.

The Plugin adds a button to the tool bar.

When you click on the button, a small popup opens asking to provide an image file name (ex: my_image.jpg)

Then, the plugin constructs the full URLs of the image (ex: http://www.example.com/images/my_image.jpg) and insert it into the TinyMCE editor. All that works fine and the plugin looks like this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('imgc500', function(editor) {
    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.addButton('imgc500', {
        text: 'C500',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            // Open window
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Please enter filename: ',
                body: [
                    {type: 'textbox', name: 'file', label: 'Image'},
                    {type: 'textbox', name: 'caption', label: 'Caption'},
                    {type: 'textbox', name: 'copyr', label: 'CopyRight'}
                ],
                onsubmit: function(e) {
                    // Insert content when the window form is submitted

                    editor.insertContent('<center><div class="" style="width:504px;"><div><img src="http://www.example.com/images/' + e.data.file + '"' + ' border="0" width="500"></div><div class=""> <div>' + e.data.caption + ' </div><div>Photo: &copy ' + e.data.copyr + ' </div></div></div></center><br />');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The above code works fine.

## NOW THE ISSUE

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

- Instead of providing the filename, I would like to provide a PHOTO_ID.
- Once I hit submit, An jQuery Ajax function will retrieve the PHOTO_ID and submit a JSON request to the website that will return a JSON message with the actual filename to be inserted in the TinyMCE editor.
- My new plugin looks like this:

  tinymce.PluginManager.add('imgc500', function(editor) {
      // Add a button that opens a window
      editor.addButton('imgc500', {
          text: 'C500',
          icon: false,
          onclick: function() {
              // Open window
              editor.windowManager.open({
                  title: 'Please enter PHOTO ID: ',
                  body: [
                      {type: 'textbox', name: 'photoid', label: 'PHOTO ID'}

  ```
              ],
              onsubmit: function(e) {
                  // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                  var lData = {
                      thephotoid: e.data.photoid
                  }
                  //alert(e.data.photoid);
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                      $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://www.example.com/wservices/get_photo_by_phid",
                            data: lData,
                            //dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   

                            error: function(xhr, error) {
                                  alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status + ' Message = ' + error);get

                              },

                            success: function(result){                                
                              var lphoto_500 = result.thepicture[0].PHOTO_500x500;
                              var lphoto_caption = result.thepicture[0].PHOTO_CAPTION;
                              var lphoto_cr = result.thepicture[0].PHOTO_CR;  

                              editor.insertContent('<div class=""><img src="http://www.example.com/images/' + lphoto_500 + '"' + ' border="0" width="500"></div><div class="photocaption" style="font-size:12px; margin-top:-5px; margin-bottom:10px;">' + lphoto_caption + ' <span style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-copyright" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + lphoto_cr + ' </span></div>');                             
                            }
                          });

                  }); //End Document Ready Function...                                    

              }
          });
      }
  });
  ```

  });

That does not work !

What I have noticed is that everything between "`$(document).ready(function(){`"

and

"`});   //End Document Ready Function...`"

is not getting executed.

It looks like the plugin does not recognize jQuery...

Am I missing something ?

JackD

Comment: I managed to make it work.

Comment: jQuery was not needed. Only pure Ajax and that works fine, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work.

jQuery was not needed. Only pure Ajax.

The "onsubmit" function in the plugin just looks like this:

```
        onsubmit: function(e) {
            // Insert content when the window form is submitted             
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var lurl =  "http://www.example.com/wservices/photos/get_photo_by_phid/" + e.data.photoid;
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var MPhoto = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        var lphoto_800 = MPhoto.thepicture[0].PHOTO_800xyyy;
                        var lphoto_caption = MPhoto.thepicture[0].PHOTO_CAPTION;
                        var lphoto_cr = MPhoto.thepicture[0].PHOTO_CR;  
                        editor.insertContent('<div class="cp-thumb"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/' + lphoto_800 + '"' + ' border="0" width="100%"></div><div class="photocaption" style="font-size:12px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px;">' + lphoto_caption + ' <span style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-copyright" aria-hidden="true"></i> Photo: ' + lphoto_cr + '</span></div>');                              
                } 
              };                    
              xhttp.open("GET", lurl, true);
              xhttp.send();                 
        }
```